# order n polynomial long division question

Tags: polynomials, roots, divisibility

I am trying to show that 1 is a zero of $P(x)=x^n - (n+1)x + n$ by dividing it through by $x-1$.

Now, It's definitely a zero because $P(1) = 0$, but from the long division I'm getting P(1) = -1

$ \hspace{3em} x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + ... - (n+1) $   <- should be $-n$

$x-1{)}\hspace{-0.35em}\overline{\hspace{0.5em} x^{n+1} + 0x^n + 0x^{n-1} + ...-(n+1)x +n \hspace{7em}}$

$ \hspace{2.5em}  x^{n+1} - x^n $

$ \hspace{5em}\overline{ x^n + 0x^{n-1} + ... -(n+1)x +n  }  $

$ \hspace{5em}{\underline{x^n  - x^{n-1} \hspace{7em}}} $

$ \hspace{7em}{x^{n-1}+ ... -(n+1)x +n } $

$ \hspace{12em}{...} $

$ \hspace{12em}{{-(n+1)x +n \hspace{4em}}} $

$ \hspace{8em}{\underline{\hspace{4em}{-(n+1)x +n+1}}} $

$ \hspace{18em} -1 $

And the quotient is definitely correct because I have a proof by induction for $x^n - (n+1)x + n =(x-1)(x^n + x^{n-1} + ... + x -n)$, but just can't seem to confirm it through long division.

Can anyone help me out?

TIA

Comment: Experimenting, I set $n=5$ and then used polynomial long division to find that $$(x^5 - 6x + 5) \div (x-1) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x - 5.$$

Comment: Without long division or induction, write $\,P(x) = x(x^{n-1} - 1) - n (x - 1) = (x-1)(\dots)\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last 5 rows of division should be \begin{array}{rrrrr} x^2 & + & -(n+1)x & + &  n \\ x^2 &+&  -x && \\ \hline &&-nx&+& n \\ &&-nx & + & n \\ \hline &&&&0.
\end{array}

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how you get $-x$?

Comment: By subtracting $x^{n+1}-x^n, x^n-x^{n-1},\dots$ from $P$, we get $x^n-(n+1)x+n, x^{n-1}-(n+1)x+n,\dots, x^2-(n+1)x+n$. To delete $x^2$, we subtract $x(x-1)= x^2-x$ from it.

Comment: Ahh, yes I get it now. I was missing the $x^2$ value from the previous remainder operation. Thanks again.